# Keras how to view node connections?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

If I understand a neural net correctly - it is just a graph of **nodes** and **edges** where each node in a given layer is connected to every node in the following layer.

The nodes have weights and the edges have weights? And you do some multiplication of these values to get a prediction.

### [image]

Given a 2 layer model (with 2 input nodes 'a & b' and 1 output node 'c'), this is what I am after:

```
| source | destination | value |
+--------+-------------+-------+
| a      | c           | 0.01  |
| b      | c           | 0.03  |
```

But when I call `model.weights` (albeit on a more complex model) I get a bunch of keyless np arrays with no way to tell which values belong to which nodes.

```
[<tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(8, 12) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.31751466,  0.20620143,  0.09791961, -0.08813753,  0.2515421 ,
        -0.53187364, -0.15702713,  0.0267031 , -0.48389524, -0.13240823,
         0.39453653, -0.39209265],
       [ 0.31308496, -0.38468117, -0.03970708,  0.2889997 ,  0.03803336,
         0.04796927, -0.5140167 ,  0.04645742,  0.08511442, -0.09435426,
         0.03105392, -0.17520434],
       [ 0.05365064, -0.05402106, -0.02931813,  0.13150737,  0.08898667,
         0.20198704,  0.28716817,  0.21081768, -0.09572094,  0.14665389,
        -0.3083644 , -0.47491354],
       [-0.36734372, -0.12509695, -0.16984704, -0.19592582,  0.24023046,
        -0.28856498,  0.11084742,  0.12101128,  0.00146453, -0.4996385 ,
        -0.23521361,  0.24130017],
       [ 0.21538568, -0.08531788, -0.32247233, -0.09213281, -0.39390212,
         0.05042276,  0.22282743, -0.11438937, -0.00920196,  0.12748554,
        -0.02741051, -0.12594655],
       [ 0.3057384 , -0.20449257,  0.16837521,  0.21493798, -0.14034544,
         0.45435148, -0.0548106 ,  0.07033874,  0.39275315, -0.3332669 ,
        -0.10222256,  0.14674312],
       [ 0.36575058,  0.07205153, -0.14340317, -0.57348907,  0.7167731 ,
        -0.29590985,  0.6351    , -0.6615748 , -0.23423046, -0.1065482 ,
         0.7084621 ,  0.02146828],
       [-0.14760445, -0.4926324 ,  0.30986223,  0.4067813 ,  0.32313958,
        -0.39595246,  0.12813015, -0.3088377 , -0.7285755 ,  0.6085407 ,
         0.39351743, -0.09248918]], dtype=float32)>, 
  <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(12,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([-1.1890789 ,  0.        , -0.43765482,  0.5292001 , -0.94201744,
        0.44064137, -0.5898111 ,  0.8738893 , -0.62948394,  0.9394948 ,
        0.47176355,  0.        ], dtype=float32)>, 
  <tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(12, 8) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.18743241, -0.04509293,  0.26035592, -0.40080604, -0.2120734 ,
         0.0604641 ,  0.17452721, -0.25245216],
       [-0.4116977 ,  0.4476785 ,  0.13495606,  0.38070595, -0.16811815,
        -0.5323667 , -0.41471216,  0.49056184],
       [-0.43843648, -0.01767761,  0.03876654,  0.279591  , -0.64866304,
         0.4605058 ,  0.50288963,  0.46865177],
       [-0.50431   ,  0.26749972, -0.4822985 ,  0.11643535,  0.34190154,
         0.28961414, -0.19484225,  0.32788265],
       [-0.4659909 ,  0.12863334, -0.17177017,  0.27696657, -0.08261362,
         0.1787579 , -0.49217325, -0.419283  ],
       [-0.31586087,  0.4421215 , -0.35133213, -0.40784043,  0.3213457 ,
         0.08262701, -0.20723267, -0.4305911 ],
       [-0.32226318, -0.3479017 , -0.48984393, -0.19052912,  0.27398133,
        -0.18631694, -0.42036086, -0.31824118],
       [-0.04223084, -0.38938865, -0.33997327, -0.7986885 , -0.12062006,
        -0.37880445,  0.06364141,  0.41674942],
       [-0.07699671, -1.0260301 , -0.38287994,  0.46872973, -0.32630473,
         0.37103057,  0.06274027, -0.25317484],
       [-0.11334842,  0.29602957,  0.01759415,  0.07748368, -0.0767558 ,
         0.13787462, -0.31502756,  0.17331126],
       [-0.5030543 , -0.23578712, -0.38978124,  0.01187875, -0.02882512,
        -0.5208091 , -0.4208508 , -0.08294159],
       [ 0.04435921,  0.545004  ,  0.07590699,  0.21470094, -0.46099266,
        -0.25307545, -0.31362575,  0.3284188 ]], dtype=float32)>,
  <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(8,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 0.        ,  1.3254918 , -0.18484406, -0.0136466 ,  1.2459729 ,
       -1.331188  , -0.01439124,  0.9184486 ], dtype=float32)>,
  <tf.Variable 'dense_3/kernel:0' shape=(8, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.27390796],
       [-0.40990734],
       [-0.12878264],
       [-0.43434066],
       [-0.04099607],
       [ 0.57922167],
       [ 0.3830525 ],
       [-0.47695825]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_3/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([-1.3391492], dtype=float32)>]
```

Is there a JSON/dictionary-like way to get what I am after?

Answer (score 1):

The "sources" and "destinations" of those edges don't have names like "a" and "b", they're just the *k*th neuron of the *n*th layer. The weights, then, are just an array. For example, `weights[n][i][j]` might be the weight of the edge connecting the *i*th neuron of layer *n* to the *j*th neuron of layer *n*+1. In this paradigm, the weights of your textbook example would look like

```
[[[ 0.8 0.4 0.3 ] [ 0.2 0.9 0.5 ]]
 [[ 0.3 0.5 0.9 ]]]
```

When you take into account the fact that each neuron can have a *bias* as well as incoming weights, and that different layers' different numbers of neurons would make the 3D array ragged (which is inconvenient), you might find that the most convenient way to store it is as a structure that contains several 2D arrays (each one containing the weights for one pair of layers) and several 1D arrays (each containing the biases for one layer), all of different sizes... which is exactly what the dump you provided shows.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I was unnecessarily worried about overlapping combinations of nodes.